# How to make UART-UART cable

Tags: connector, uart, cables

I am software developer and I need to make cable to connect this http://lib.chipdip.ru/036/DOC001036112.pdf usb adapter (which I connect to USB port of my PC) to UART port of my A13 Olinuxino.

As I understand I must connect them this way:

UART(ADAPTER) : UART (A13)
ground(-) : ground(-)
plus(+) : plus(+)
RX  :  TX
TX  :  RX

Am I right?

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard four-pin header as used with the BeagleBone, et al. See http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBone_Black_Serial (even though this talks about integrated USB cables.) I'm thinking you probably don't need to connect the + cable. i.e., you only need three wires: tx/rx and a ground reference. The stuff is powered at either end already.

Comment: Reading the PDF linked, I agree with @jdv. Do not connect the + to +. This would only be used if the USB adapter were used to power the connected board. Since the Olinuxino is self powered, connecting this could cause problems if the voltages are not quite the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A summary of @jdv and @DoxyLover's answer-as-a-comment:

```
UART(ADAPTER) : UART (A13)
    ground(-) : ground(-)
           RX : TX
           TX : RX
```

and no connection of either plus(+) pin: those are for powering the device, and since the OLinuXino has its own power, connecting the plus(+) pins could cause problems if the voltages are different.